# What is a word for "moving place to place, stopping at each to make a delivery"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ex.

"She _______ed around campus, stopping at each familiar classroom to deliver a farewell gift to her teachers."

Comment: Are you looking for ***toured***, or ***did the rounds***?

Comment: **ran errands**, **shuttled**?

Comment: She "walked" if she walked and "ran" if she "ran". She "moved'.

Comment: Was she in a vehicle, bicycle? Walked, ran, hurried, strolled, stormed?

Comment: +1 for shuttled, I think that is an answer. Go, stop, go, stop, etc.

Comment: If it weren't a verb that you needed, I'd suggest milk run, defined as a trip involving stops at several locations that facilitates either distribution or collection.

Comment: Yes, **shuttled** is good, a metaphor from weaving. You could also try **scuttled.**

Comment: +1 for "toured". Alternative: "*She made a round of farewell visits in the campus, stopping at each familiar classroom to deliver a gift to her teachers.*"

Comment: She [**steamed**](http://www.britannica.com/technology/tramp-steamer) around campus, calling on each familiar classroom to bestow farewell gifts upon her teachers.

Answer (score 9):

**make/go the rounds**

> She made her rounds around campus, stopping at each familiar classroom
>   to deliver a farewell gift to her teachers."

```
*make/go the rounds*
1. To go from place to place, as on business or for entertainment: 
    - a delivery truck making the rounds
    - students going the rounds in the entertainment district.
```

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rounds

Additionally, in the health care space, `rounding` is the act of a nurse or practitioner who checks up on patients at regular intervals.

https://americannursetoday.com/value-purposeful-rounding/

Comment: I would have said *She made her rounds of the campus...* to avoid repetition of *round* in *around*.

Comment: @WS2 Good point, or even *She made her rounds about campus*

Answer (score 6):

Would there be anything wrong with saying:

***She went around campus, stopping at each familiar classroom...?***

Or is that too simple?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to and are okay with it, you can squeeze a term from a technical field into regular conversation.

> Try Milk run - a round trip that facilitates either distribution or collection.

[Wikipedia link for milk run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_run)
Also, search it and look around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try *ramble*.

> To walk casually or leisurely.

This is number #2 meaning [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ramble) with an example sentence: *[She] rambled over to the neighbor's house.*

This clearly shows intented action.

---

From [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramble):

> Walk for pleasure, typically without a definite route.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was under the impression that the three numbered meanings are exclusive (logical OR between them, and not AND).

Comment: @Matsmath When there are multiple definitions, it's more useful for you to post just the one you're focusing on than to include ones that are irrelevant.

Comment: Even if so we have no particular reason to think that (2) or (3) apply anyway.To me ["walk for pleasure in the countryside."](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramble) would be more what rambling conjurs up anyway. Definitely not “moving place to place, stopping at each to make a delivery”

Comment: @MartinSmith: That is a *noun*, you are quoting. I have improved my answer.

Comment: Rats, I take that back. I am somewhat surprised how the american English and [british] English pages are different: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramble vs http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ramble.

Comment: Ah that explains it then. The example usage you give at the top just sounds to me as though it should be "amble"!

Comment: There is nothing in the question which suggests she took her time and *rambled*. She may have been doing it hurriedly, running between places.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, *she **hopped** around campus, stopping at each familiar classroom to deliver a farewell gift to her teachers.*

> hop
>
> *informal* pass quickly from one place to another.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hop)

Answer (score 1):

The usual (cliched?) phrasing would employ 'circulate':

> She **circulated** around campus, stopping at each familiar classroom to deliver a farewell gift to her teachers.

In this sense, 'circulate' is intransitive, and has this meaning:

> 2. To move around, as from person to person or place to place,

(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. S.v. "circulated." Retrieved May 7 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/circulated )

Your delivery connotations invoke a resonance with another--here indirect--transitive meaning of 'circulate':

> 5. to cause to pass from place to place, person to person, etc.; disseminate; distribute.

(Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. S.v. "circulated." Retrieved May 7 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/circulated )